# Wildcard for table permissions

Tags: mysql, permissions

I want to grant a user permission to `select,insert,update,delete` on a few tables in the `prod` database. However, I find it time consuming to write each grant statement out per table. Is it possible to use a wildcard?

There are 300 tables, the user only needs access to 18 of them. The tables the user needs access to are prefixed 'vs_'.

Can I do a `grant select,insert,update,delete on prod.vs_\*` ?  I know `prod.\*` is possible but wasn't sure on the prefix of a table.

Comment: You could just try it and see if it works.

Comment: Is this for Windows or Linux (please say Linux because Windows always takes more work) ?

Answer (score 5):

No, the wildcard for table names can only be `*`, and does not permit other characters or patterns.

You could generate the 18 GRANT statements you need:

```
SELECT CONCAT('GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON prod.`', TABLE_NAME, '` TO ...;')
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'prod' AND TABLE_NAME LIKE 'vs\_%';
```

Capture the output of that query, and then run it as a series of statements.

Answer (score 5):

Your probably need to use the INFORMATION_SCHEMA to help you make the GRANTS on all vs tables.

## SAMPLE DATA

I will create a database `edwards` with 3 tables for each family member

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS edwards;
CREATE DATABASE edwards;
USE edwards
CREATE TABLE rolando_tb1
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, num INT NOT NULL) ENGINE=MyISAM;
CREATE TABLE rolando_tb2 LIKE rolando_tb1;
CREATE TABLE rolando_tb3 LIKE rolando_tb1;
CREATE TABLE pamela_tb1 LIKE rolando_tb1;
CREATE TABLE pamela_tb2 LIKE rolando_tb1;
CREATE TABLE pamela_tb3 LIKE rolando_tb1;
CREATE TABLE dominique_tb1 LIKE rolando_tb1;
CREATE TABLE dominique_tb2 LIKE rolando_tb1;
CREATE TABLE dominique_tb3 LIKE rolando_tb1;
CREATE TABLE diamond_tb1 LIKE rolando_tb1;
CREATE TABLE diamond_tb2 LIKE rolando_tb1;
CREATE TABLE diamond_tb3 LIKE rolando_tb1;
SHOW TABLES;
```

Here are the commands executed

```
mysql> DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS edwards;
Query OK, 12 rows affected (0.08 sec)

mysql> CREATE DATABASE edwards;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> USE edwards
Database changed
mysql> CREATE TABLE rolando_tb1
    -> (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, num INT NOT NULL) ENGINE=MyISAM;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE rolando_tb2 LIKE rolando_tb1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE rolando_tb3 LIKE rolando_tb1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE pamela_tb1 LIKE rolando_tb1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE pamela_tb2 LIKE rolando_tb1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE pamela_tb3 LIKE rolando_tb1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE dominique_tb1 LIKE rolando_tb1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE dominique_tb2 LIKE rolando_tb1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE dominique_tb3 LIKE rolando_tb1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE diamond_tb1 LIKE rolando_tb1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE diamond_tb2 LIKE rolando_tb1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE diamond_tb3 LIKE rolando_tb1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> SHOW TABLES;
+-------------------+
| Tables_in_edwards |
+-------------------+
| diamond_tb1       |
| diamond_tb2       |
| diamond_tb3       |
| dominique_tb1     |
| dominique_tb2     |
| dominique_tb3     |
| pamela_tb1        |
| pamela_tb2        |
| pamela_tb3        |
| rolando_tb1       |
| rolando_tb2       |
| rolando_tb3       |
+-------------------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

## SAMPLE USER

Let's create a use called `pam@localhost` with the password `pam`

```
mysql> GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO pam@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'pam';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR pam@localhost;
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for pam@localhost                                                                                   |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'pam'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*F925CA006C127B610C43AB06E16F92EF8712F90B' |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Using the INFORMATION_SCHEMA (@BillKarwin gets +1 for being faster and concise), let's scult the grants for the three tables that start with `pamela_`

Using this query

```
SELECT CONCAT('GRANT SELECT,INSERT ON ',db,'.',tb,' TO pam@localhost;') grant_command
FROM (SELECT table_schema db,table_name tb FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema='edwards' AND table_name LIKE 'pamela\_%') A;
```

Here is the output

```
mysql> SELECT CONCAT('GRANT SELECT,INSERT ON ',db,'.',tb,' TO pam@localhost;') grant_command
    -> FROM (SELECT table_schema db,table_name tb FROM information_schema.tables
    -> WHERE table_schema='edwards' AND table_name LIKE 'pamela\_%') A;
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| grant_command                                               |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT SELECT,INSERT ON edwards.pamela_tb1 TO pam@localhost; |
| GRANT SELECT,INSERT ON edwards.pamela_tb2 TO pam@localhost; |
| GRANT SELECT,INSERT ON edwards.pamela_tb3 TO pam@localhost; |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

I'll copy and paste them. Then I'll show the grants

```
mysql> GRANT SELECT,INSERT ON edwards.pamela_tb1 TO pam@localhost;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> GRANT SELECT,INSERT ON edwards.pamela_tb2 TO pam@localhost;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> GRANT SELECT,INSERT ON edwards.pamela_tb3 TO pam@localhost;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR pam@localhost;
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for pam@localhost                                                                                   |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'pam'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*F925CA006C127B610C43AB06E16F92EF8712F90B' |
| GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON `edwards`.`pamela_tb1` TO 'pam'@'localhost'                                        |
| GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON `edwards`.`pamela_tb3` TO 'pam'@'localhost'                                        |
| GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON `edwards`.`pamela_tb2` TO 'pam'@'localhost'                                        |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

## LOGIN AND TEST USER

```
C:\windows\system32>mysql -upam -ppam
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 6
Server version: 5.6.15 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> show grants;
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for pam@localhost                                                                                   |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'pam'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*F925CA006C127B610C43AB06E16F92EF8712F90B' |
| GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON `edwards`.`pamela_tb1` TO 'pam'@'localhost'                                        |
| GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON `edwards`.`pamela_tb3` TO 'pam'@'localhost'                                        |
| GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON `edwards`.`pamela_tb2` TO 'pam'@'localhost'                                        |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> use edwards
Database changed
mysql> select * from pamela_tb2;
Empty set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from rolando_tb1;
ERROR 1142 (42000): SELECT command denied to user 'pam'@'localhost' for table 'rolando_tb1'
mysql> select * from pamela_tb3;
Empty set (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into pamela_db1 (num) values (11),(22),(33);
ERROR 1142 (42000): INSERT command denied to user 'pam'@'localhost' for table 'pamela_db1'
mysql> insert into pamela_tb1 (num) values (11),(22),(33);
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> insert into rolando_tb1 (num) values (11),(22),(33);
ERROR 1142 (42000): INSERT command denied to user 'pam'@'localhost' for table 'rolando_tb1'
mysql> select * from pamela_tb1;
+----+-----+
| id | num |
+----+-----+
|  1 |  11 |
|  2 |  22 |
|  3 |  33 |
+----+-----+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> delete from pamela_tb1 where id = 2;
ERROR 1142 (42000): DELETE command denied to user 'pam'@'localhost' for table 'pamela_tb1'
mysql>
```

Looks like it works for pam having SELECT and INSERT

In your case, [@BillKarwin already said what to do in his answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/65270/877).

If you like my answer, [accept Bill's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/65270/877) since here came up with the concept before me.